# Integration of acceleration matrix and updating input with output

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-integration

I have 2 questions regarding Integration.

I have an input matrix with 12 rows and 1 column. First 6 rows are vertical displacement, velocity, acceleration, and Torsional displacement, velocity, acceleration, respectively.

1. I am trying to integrate acceleration (vertical and torsional) matrix (`output3`) to get velocity and displacement, but I am getting an error:

   > Error using trapz (line 59) LENGTH(X) must equal the length of Y in dim 1.
2. And I want to replace the input with my output after integration.

Could anyone please help me with this?

```
t_start = 0;
dt = 0.0128;
N = 46995;
t = t_start + (0:N-1)*dt;
t1 = t_start + (0:23497-1)*dt;
t2 = 300.7616 + (0:23498-1)*dt;

InputActual = [1.499;-0.243;-0.379;-0.00179;0.0216;0.0248;40;36.080;0.493;40;36.120;0.449];
output3=zeros(2,23498);
velocity=zeros(2,23498);
displacement = zeros(2,23498);

for i = 1:23498-1  
output3(:,i) = net(InputActual);
velocity(:,i) = trapz(t2,output3(:,i),1);
displacement(:,i)= trapz(t2,vel(:,i),1);
InputActual   = [output3(1, ii);velocity(1, ii);displacement(1, ii);output3(2, ii);velocity(2, ii);displacement(2, ii);InputActual(7:end, ii+1)];
end
```

Comment: What is `net`? And please rename your `disp` variable; that is also the name of a MATLAB function, and overloading that might give you some strange errors when displaying something.

Comment: Also, `input` is undefined

Comment: net is neural network toolbox.

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis, Thank you very much for your reply. I am doing my master thesis using neural networks. I have created neural network and trained with known set of data, It's working good. Now I want to test it unknown data, I know the input acceleration in the first time step of t2, i will predict the output acceleration using neural network and the integrate them to get velocity and displacement. Finally replacing the input with output data. I want to this in each time step of t2. Can you help me with this?